# AWS Java Lambda not connecting to Internet - no VPC

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created a Lambda function in AWS, it does not have a VPC configured, which seems to be the common reason for missing internet access, yet it seemingly cannot connect to the internet. I'm sure I'm making some obvious mistake but I can't really think of anything.

I've tried to recreate the connections my Lambda uses in a main function locally and it works just fine there.

### Output of main method on my machine

```
2021-09-12 14:54:05  INFO  FetchCommodityPrice - google.com reached? true
2021-09-12 14:54:05  INFO  FetchCommodityPrice - fred.stlouisfed.org reached? true
2021-09-12 14:54:05  DEBUG Logger - [FredApi#observations] ---> GET https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=PSOILUSDM&api_key=[REMOVED]&observation_start=2021-06-01&file_type=json HTTP/1.1
2021-09-12 14:54:05  DEBUG Logger - [FredApi#observations] ---> END HTTP (0-byte body)
2021-09-12 14:54:06  DEBUG Logger - [FredApi#observations] <--- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (1035ms)
2021-09-12 14:54:06  DEBUG Logger - [FredApi#observations] connection: keep-alive
2021-09-12 14:54:06  DEBUG Logger - [FredApi#observations] content-length: 483
[...response body...]
2021-09-12 14:54:06  DEBUG Logger - [FredApi#observations] <--- END HTTP (483-byte body)
2021-09-12 14:54:06  DEBUG FetchCommodityPrice - latest: 1451.68977904762
```

### Output of my Lambda execution

```
START RequestId: [request-id] Version: $LATEST
2021-09-12 12:58:06 [request-id] INFO  FetchCommodityPrice - google.com reached? false
2021-09-12 12:58:09 [request-id] INFO  FetchCommodityPrice - fred.stlouisfed.org reached? false
2021-09-12 12:58:09 [request-id] DEBUG FetchCommodityPrice - Fetching data for commodity PSOILUSDM
2021-09-12 12:58:09 [request-id] DEBUG Logger - [FredApi#observations] ---> GET https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=PSOILUSDM&api_key=[REMOVED]&observation_start=2021-06-12&file_type=json HTTP/1.1
2021-09-12 12:58:09 [request-id] DEBUG Logger - [FredApi#observations] ---> END HTTP (0-byte body)
END RequestId: [request-id]
REPORT RequestId: [request-id]  Duration: 10010.46 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms   Memory Size: 150 MB Max Memory Used: 134 MB Init Duration: 1904.89 ms   
2021-09-12T12:58:14.479Z [request-id] Task timed out after 10.01 seconds
```

### Code of my Lambda Handler

```
package com.kwjoshua.soyprice;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.kwjoshua.soyprice.fred.FredApi;
import com.kwjoshua.soyprice.fred.Observation;
import com.kwjoshua.soyprice.fred.SeriesObservations;
import feign.Feign;
import feign.jackson.JacksonDecoder;
import feign.slf4j.Slf4jLogger;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Optional;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class FetchCommodityPrice implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FetchCommodityPrice.class);

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final String fredApiKey;
    private final FredApi fredApi;

    public FetchCommodityPrice() {
        this.objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder().findAndAddModules().build();
        this.fredApiKey = System.getenv("FRED_API_KEY");
        this.fredApi = createFredApiClient(System.getenv("FRED_API_URL"));
    }

    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent requestEvent, Context context) {
        Optional<Commodity> commodity = Commodity.byPath(requestEvent.getPath());
        if (commodity.isEmpty()) {
            return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().withStatusCode(404);
        }
        testConnection();
        try {
            return okResponse(getCommodityPrice(commodity.get()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().withStatusCode(500);
        }
    }

    private static void testConnection() {
        logReachable("google.com");
        logReachable("fred.stlouisfed.org");
    }

    private static void logReachable(String host) {
        try {
            logger.info(host + " reached? " + InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(2000));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error trying to reach host '" + host + "'", e);
        }
    }

    private CommodityPrice getCommodityPrice(Commodity commodity) {
        logger.debug("Fetching data for commodity " + commodity.getId());
        SeriesObservations observations = fredApi.observations(
                commodity.getId(), fredApiKey, LocalDate.now().minusMonths(3).toString());
        Observation lastObservation = observations.getObservations().get(observations.getObservations().size() - 1);
        logger.debug("last observed price: " + lastObservation.getValue());
        return new CommodityPrice(lastObservation.getValue(), lastObservation.getDate());
    }

    private APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent okResponse(CommodityPrice commodityPriceJson) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
                .withStatusCode(200)
                .withBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(commodityPriceJson))
                .withIsBase64Encoded(false);
    }

    private static FredApi createFredApiClient(String fredApiUrl) {
        return Feign.builder()
                    .logger(new Slf4jLogger())
                    .logLevel(feign.Logger.Level.FULL)
                    .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
                    .target(FredApi.class, fredApiUrl);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testConnection();
        FredApi api = createFredApiClient("https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred");
        SeriesObservations observations = api.observations(Commodity.OIL.getId(), args[0], "2021-06-01");
        logger.debug("latest: " + observations.getObservations().get(observations.getObservations().size() - 1).getValue());
    }
}
```

### VPC configuration of Lambda

[image: Screenshot illustrating no VPC is configured]

Comment: I see you have a test trying to connect to google.com in your code, does that work?

Comment: Was this Lambda function ever connected to a VPC? Any chance you are testing a different version?

Comment: @MarkB Hi Mark, it works in my main function, not when I execute the Lambda, see the "Output of my Lambda execution" line 2.

Comment: @jarmod I had at one point connected it to a VPC, but that was only after already trying to solve this issue for some time. The lambda currently only has 1 version (or rather: no versions? I mean to say I've not published any versions of it).

Comment: @kjosh I don't care what works on your local machine, I'm asking if you can hit google from your Lambda function. That would indicate that the other API is blocking AWS IPs, which is not uncommon. You could also test it by running a simple `curl` command from an EC2 instance to see if that API is blocking AWS.

Comment: Hi @MarkB, I didn't refer to the output of my local machine, but to the output of the lambda log in my question under "Output of my Lambda execution", where you can see that it is trying to reach google.com and failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a timeout issue. The site does answer, but much slower than it does when I connect from my local network.

Increasing the maximum lambda function timeout solved the issue.

Comment: Does this also explain the timed out ICMP ECHO to google.com?

Comment: Hi @jarmod, no, I still can't quite figure out why that worked on my machine and not in the Lambda execution. I upped the timeout to 15s on that and it still didn't work. However: a connection to https://google.com via java.net.URLConnection#connect did work.

Comment: Not sure we understand root cause at this point. Unless the target website is throttling your Lambda client, e.g. because the request is from an AWS IP range and the target deems AWS to be an attack vector, I don't see why network performance would be worse. I'd be tempted to create a brand new Lambda function (without VPC), import this code, and re-test.